# Send element id from div to javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to trigger a file input using javascript. I am using Django formset and I have obtained the id of the input fields current my Javascript functions looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show-image-upload-inputs").click(function(){
      $("#image-upload-div").toggle();
    });

    function open_input (id,input_id) {
      $(this.id).on("click", function () {
        $(this.input_id).trigger("click");
      });
    }
  });
```

And in my HTML I am passing them to the function, using onclick:

```
<div id="file-0-selector" class="add-image" onclick="open_input(this.id,document.getElementById('id_form-0-image'))"><i class="mt-2 fas fa-plus fa-5x"></i></div>
```

However, when I click on it I do not see the upload box opening, I was wondering how I can achieve this. I have acquired the image input fields form my formset and the id seems to be correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, you can use vanilla js?

Comment: `open_input` is just binding another "click" handler?

Comment: Are `$(this.id)` and `$(this.input_id)` really correct?  AFAICT your inline JS is passing `id` as a string, and `input_id` as DOM node (JS, not jQuery).  But to use your `id` as a jQuery selector, you'd do `$('#' + id)`, not `$(this.id)`.  I have no idea what `$(this.input_id)` will do, given `input_id` is a JS DOM node ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `open_input` function is just binding another click handler, you should remove this and to select an element by id in jQuery you need to prefix the id with `#` and you don't need to access variables using `this`.

```
function open_input(input_id) {
  $("#" + input_id).trigger("click");
}
```

Now your `onclick` becomes a little more simple as you don't need to select the element you only need to pass it's id

```
onclick="open_input('id_form-0-image')"
```